# Piranha CMS - Exporting from Development to Live

Tags: piranha-cms

I'm creating a group of websites using Piranha CMS v2.2.5.0. My user base would like to migrate individual pages/page types from the QA environment to the production environment. Is there a simple way to migrate individual entities. I would rather not resort to migrating the entire database.

Answer (score 0):

There are no built in support for this at the moment.